# scale div using hammer.js

Tags: jquery, multi-touch, resizable, hammer.js

Hi friends I am wokking on mobile site and in this site there is a `div#someId` which has `<img>` I fixed the image height and width using css `height:100%; height:auto;`

Now the requirement is I want to resize the `div#someId` and also want to drag it

I have implement `hammer.js` in my code to enable multi-touch to `pinchzoom` and `pinchout` the `div#someId` but cant understand how to get this done

Is there any other way-out to complete this task. you can check my code below

**SCRIPT**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script src="hammer.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
    var element = document.getElementById('tapdiv');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function(event) {
        alert('hello!');
    })

}, false);
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="tapdiv" style="width:200px; height:200px; background:red; color:#fff;">asd</div>
```

PLease help me guys .. THanks in advance ..

Answer (score 1):

i have done this a few days ago.
you can view the example live on: http://m.v-s-b.de/de/strecken-skizzen/vsb-tarifzonenplan/

you have to create a div-container with the following stylesheet

```
.imageWindow {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}

.imageWindow img {
    -ms-transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px);
    transform: scale(1) translate(0px, 0px);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

with hammerjs now you can pan and drag the img inside this div.

i have used canJS 2 and hammerJS 1.1.3
feel free to look into my code http://jsfiddle.net/wpLJQ/

maybe the canJS Map soltuion is not the best, it can be easier

Edit:
here is my first solution without canJS
http://jsfiddle.net/fnCaP/